# Can not bound xml data to dropdown list in c#

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I have one xml file like this :

```
<DATASET>
<RECORD ClientId="1398" Name="Mausami Pandit"></RECORD>
<RECORD ClientId="1121" Name="Tony Mead"></RECORD>
<RECORD ClientId="1124" Name="Frank Lead"></RECORD>
<RECORD ClientId="1008" Name="Julie Lily"></RECORD>
</DATASET>
```

I need to use this xml data to the dropdown menu in c#.net.

```
 string s13 = GetClientXML(); // by this function i am taking xml data to s13 variable.
 StringReader theReader = new StringReader(s13);
 DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
 DataRow row1 = theDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
 row1["ClientId"] = 0;
 row1["Name"] = "-- Select --";
 theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row1);
 theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);                                    

 // ddlassto is my combobox. System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox                                                         
 ddlassto.DataSource = theDataSet.Tables[0];
 ddlassto.ValueMember = "ClientId";
 ddlassto.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

But this is not working. Its not populating into the dropdown list.

Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = XElement.Parse(GetClientXML()).Descendants()
           .Select(node=> new{ClientId =(string)node.Attribute("ClientId"), Name = (string)node.Attribute("Name")}).ToList();

ddlassto.DataSource = items;
ddlassto.ValueMember = "ClientId";
ddlassto.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

store the xml in a data set and then assign it to dropdownlist..

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("xmlfile.xml");
ddlassto.DataSource = ds; or ddlassto.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
ddlassto.TextField = "field name"; // field to display in dropdown
ddlassto.ValueField="Value Field";
ddlassto.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am doing that only. My datase name is theDataSet. but its not working.

Comment: @Mausami : in your code where is 'ddlassto.DataBind();'? Please add this at the end of 'ddlassto.DisplayMember = "Name";' line...

Comment: ddlassto is a combobox. I am not getting DataBind() property of ddlassto.

Comment: Ohh yes sorry for that... you are using windows form and i am talking about webform...

Comment: yaa.. thats ok. but do you know any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

One more method to add one by one value to your dropdownlist items If I understand your question from the comments you want to add xml values to list items try this

```
XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("xmlfile.xml");

XmlNodeList node = xdoc.SelectSingleNodes("/NewDataSet/resources/");
foreach(XmlNode n in node )
{
ListItem l = new ListItem();
    l.Text = n.InnerXml.ToString();
    ddlassto.Items.Add(l);
}
ddlassto.DataBind();
```